# Form.Hide does not prevent form from being included in screen dump

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot

**The problem**

I am using the below code to perform a screen dump. Even though I hide the form itself with `this.Hide` the form is still being included in the screen dump, which I don't want it to be.

```
this.Hide(); //Hide to not include this form in the screen dump

try
{
    Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }

        bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(LanguageMessages.MsgTextErrorScreenDump + 
        Utilities.DoubleNewLine() + exc.ToString(), 
        LanguageMessages.MsgCaptionErrorScreenDump, 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
finally
{
    this.Show(this.Owner);
}
```

**What I have tried:**
Adding the following after hiding the form, which did not make any difference:

- Sleep(1000);
- this.Repaint();
- this.Invalidate();

**My question is:**
Why does `this.Hide` not really hide the form, and thus preventing it from being included in the screen dump with the above code?

Comment: Your Windows version matters a lot.  You can take advantage of a bug in CopyFromScreen().  Set your form's Opacity property to 99% and then you no longer have to hide it.

Comment: When I run your code, the form is captured with partial transparency (so it's not quite hidden yet), and when I add `Thread.Sleep(1000);` after `this.Hide();`, it works as expected.

Comment: You've sent an instruction for the form to be hidden. In order for your form to actually process that instruction, you need to give it time on the UI thread, which I'm *guessing* you're currently hogging and trying to proceed on the assumption that the hide has happened. I.e if this is inside a button press event handler, you're on the UI thread.

Comment: It is on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: @Hans: Guess this would be a bit of a hack, wouldn't it?

Comment: Interestingly, even when I put your code into the `Form_VisibleChanged` event, there's still a ghost of the form image captured (at least on my machine). I would have expected that event not to fire until the form was completely hidden.

Comment: Try using a timer with a 1000 ms interval.  Hide the form, turn on the timer, in the tick event, turn off the timer and do the screen shot, show the form again.

Comment: Well, ApplicationDoEvents has few good uses; this could be one.

Comment: I can't reproduce on win10pro/64bit.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either on Win10 64bit myself. On slower Win7 machines it works as well, but on faster machines it does not work.

Comment: You could set `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;` `this.Hide();` then `this.Show();` `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;`. This will aslo add a nice(?) effect when if comes back :)

Comment: @LarsTech: Please make an answer as I ended up using your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat by using a timer, which would give you enough "time" to hide the form:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer hideTimer = null;
```

A full second seems to be enough:

```
this.Hide();
hideTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
hideTimer.Tick += (ts, te) => {
  hideTimer.Stop();
  hideTimer.Dispose();
  Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(this);
  using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height)) {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
      g.CopyFromScreen(bounds.Location, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
  }
  this.Show(this.Owner);
};
hideTimer.Start();
```